# Identify missing dates on dataframe datetime column with irregular frequency and fill them with associate values

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I have this df which is a sample from the actual one. Each row represent a measurement taken with intervals of approximately 20 minutes and several other columns.

```
                   datetime        value
261     2022-10-21 02:00:13     0.164299
262     2022-10-21 02:20:12     0.163009
263     2022-10-21 02:40:14     0.162298
264     2022-10-21 03:00:12     0.162846
265     2022-10-24 08:46:38     1.788360
266     2022-10-24 09:06:47     1.442915
267     2022-10-24 09:27:28     1.246774
268     2022-10-24 09:46:58     0.194352
```

As you can see, there's a gap between `2022-10-21 03:00:12` and `2022-10-24 08:46:38`. I need a way of first identify where the gaps are (there might be n of them), then fill those rows with the proper dates and nan's for the corresponding values.

Right now I'm generating the missing dates as follows:

```
# number of periods of 20 minutes between dates  
periods = (df.iloc[265,0] - df.iloc[264,0]).total_seconds() / 60.0 / 20

# dates to fill gap
pd.date_range(df.iloc[264,0], df.iloc[265,0], periods=periods)
```

Any idea of how to do this?

Edit: Expected output (I don't need the exact same minutes I added on the new rows, they are just for reference of the overall idea)

```
                   datetime        value
261     2022-10-21 02:00:13     0.164299
262     2022-10-21 02:20:12     0.163009
263     2022-10-21 02:40:14     0.162298
264     2022-10-21 03:00:12     0.162846
265     2022-10-21 03:20:00     NaN
266     2022-10-21 03:40:00     NaN
            ...
n-4     2022-10-24 08:26:00     NaN
n-3     2022-10-24 08:46:38     1.788360
n-2     2022-10-24 09:06:47     1.442915
n-1     2022-10-24 09:27:28     1.246774
n       2022-10-24 09:46:58     0.194352
```

Comment: kindly add an expected output dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try (maybe not the cleanest solution - it will try to find gaps > 40 minutes and then add 20 minute intervals with `NaN` values):

```py
mask = df["datetime"].diff() > "40 minutes"

dfs = []
for idx, row in df[mask].iterrows():
    prev_time = df.loc[idx - 1, "datetime"]
    dr = pd.date_range(
        prev_time + pd.Timedelta("20 minutes"),
        row["datetime"] - pd.Timedelta("20 minutes"),
        freq="20min",
    )
    dfs.append(
        pd.DataFrame(
            [{"datetime": dr}],
            index=[idx - 1],
        )
    )

df = pd.concat([df, *dfs]).sort_index().explode("datetime")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
               datetime     value
261 2022-10-21 02:00:13  0.164299
262 2022-10-21 02:20:12  0.163009
263 2022-10-21 02:40:14  0.162298
264 2022-10-21 03:00:12  0.162846
264 2022-10-21 03:20:12       NaN
264 2022-10-21 03:40:12       NaN

...

264 2022-10-24 08:00:12       NaN
264 2022-10-24 08:20:12       NaN
265 2022-10-24 08:46:38  1.788360
266 2022-10-24 09:06:47  1.442915
267 2022-10-24 09:27:28  1.246774
268 2022-10-24 09:46:58  0.194352
```